# smarty variable will not output

Tags: php, html, pagination, smarty

I am trying to use the paginator class from 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/ but for some reason I cannot output the pagination links in the smarty var in my template.

I have tried this:

```
function listadverts($where = null, $orderby = null, $limit = null) {         

        $pages = new Paginator;
        $pages->items_total = $this->countadverts($where);
        $pages->mid_range = 9;
        $pages->paginate();

        $row = $this->db->dbh->query('SELECT ad.*, (SELECT img.image FROM '.$this->config->db_prefix.'_images AS img WHERE img.aid = ad.aid LIMIT 1) AS img FROM '.$this->config->db_prefix.'_adverts ad WHERE (ad.approved = 1) '. $where .' ORDER BY '.$orderby.' cr_date DESC '. $pages->limit .'');

        $smarty = new Smarty();

        $smarty->assign('paginate', $pages->display_pages());
        return $row;
    }
```

and in my template I have

```
{$paginate}
```

the function

```
$pages->display_pages()
```

returns `$this->return;`

where $this->returns contains this HTML

```
$this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page) ? "<a class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$target?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">$i</a> ";
```

{$paginate|@var_dump} just returns NULL, but if i var_dump($smarty) I can see

```
["paginate"]=> object(Smarty_Variable)#114 (3) { ["value"]=> string(227) "1 2 3 4 All "
```

SOLUTION:

```
return array(0 => $row, 1 => $pages->display_pages());

$res = $adverts->listadverts();    
$app->view()->setData('adverts', $res[0]);
$app->view()->setData('paginate', $res[1]);
```

Comment: What's the SQL query for?  You assign it to $row, but then you don't seem to do anything with it except return it.  If this bit of code doesn't need to know about $row then it should be in a separate function.  Also, string concatination isn't considered a smart way to build queries if you can avoid it, especially without using an escaping function to make sure you can't suffer an SQL injection.

Comment: The code example suggests $smarty __should__ only exist inside your function. Try `global $smarty;` to make is accessible outside too or insert data into $smarty outside your functions

Comment: Garh... didn't return the $pages object ... My question update shows my solution.

Comment: @Waygood - Will you post an answer? Your comment led me to look at what I returned in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code example suggests $smarty should only exist inside your function. Try global $smarty; to make is accessible outside too or insert data into $smarty outside your functions

```
function listadverts($where = null, $orderby = null, $limit = null) { 

    $pages = new Paginator;
    $pages->items_total = $this->countadverts($where);
    $pages->mid_range = 9;
    $pages->paginate();

    $row = $this->db->dbh->query('SELECT ad.*, (SELECT img.image FROM '.$this->config->db_prefix.'_images AS img WHERE img.aid = ad.aid LIMIT 1) AS img FROM '.$this->config->db_prefix.'_adverts ad WHERE (ad.approved = 1) '. $where .' ORDER BY '.$orderby.' cr_date DESC '. $pages->limit .'');

    return $pages->display_pages();
}

$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->assign('paginate', listadverts(... ));
```